# Vector differential equations

Tags: python, matrix, vector, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a vector differential equation in Python and I keep getting an error I don't really understand.
Here is my code:

```
    import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N=100

tau_s=1
tau_n=1
R=1

t0=0
t1=10

v_rest=-65

M=[]


for i in range(N):
    M.append([])
    for j in range(N):
        M[i].append(1)

M=np.array(M)

def I(t):
    I=5   
    return I

def system(u,t):
    du=np.zeros((N,)

    du=-1/tau_s*(u-v_rest)+R*(I(t)+np.dot(M,u))

    return du

u0=v_rest*np.ones(N,)

ts=(0,1000)

sol=solve_ivp(system,ts,u0)
```

And the error I get states:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (100,100) into shape (100)
```

If I understand it properly it means that one side of the diff equation has a different shape than the other one hence Python cannot solve it, but the multiplication of M and u should yield a vector with the shape (100) so I am not sure what is happening.

Could you help me with that?

Comment: From the documentation for `solve_ivp`: "The calling signature is fun(t, y). Here t is a scalar". I think you have your arguments in `system` swapped.

Comment: @brady omg i think that was it... Thanks!

Comment: You could shorten the construction of `M` to `M=np.ones([N,N])`. Reading a matrix from a file also has a dedicated method in `numpy`, there rarely should occur a situation where you have to construct such a matrix element-by-element.

Comment: @LutzLehmann yeah you are right, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation for solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html): "The calling signature is fun(t, y). Here t is a scalar". I think you have your arguments in system swapped.

If I change the signature of system to `system(t, u)` your code runs fine for me. Although, I couldn't say whether I'm getting the expected answer or not.

Comment: yes, its a perfect solution, thanks
actually i have a new question, because now id like to add a condition that when any variable in u vector reaches -30 its set to v_rest
i tried few things but none of them worked
if statement doesnt work because u is a vector and it just doesnt work like that
changing the expression for du to du[u<-30] also failed
do you have any idea how to tackle it?

Comment: @MichalPiotrak sounds like you might need to loop through the vector and check each value individually. If you can't figure it out I recommend creating a new question with the updated code showing what you have tried. It'll be easier for someone to answer if they can see what you've tried.

Comment: i tried it but id didnt work :< 
i guess i should create a new question for that
thanks for help